# .net Core Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net-core

How do you use active directory with .net core asp.net web api?

Preferably, with out a wizard as I manage my own user system.

I achieved this in regular .net, but the libraries don’t work in .net core

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do with AD? Could you provide an example of code that you are having trouble with?

Comment: @NigelWhatling I’ll post some code when I get back to my computer.

Comment: @NigelWhatling ...hit send by mistake.  Anyway, in the original .net I’m using Microsoft.Azure.Graph to test if a user exist in AD.  I then intercept the communication, and pair it with my usher system.  The azure.graph library is .net only, not .net core

Comment: I'll admit that isn't something I've played with. Does this help at all? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore